# Implementing reflection: How to find a parent of a class

Tags: c++, reflection, generic-programming

I've got kind of a challange here. I'm working on a reflection library as both an exercise and utility kit for future projects. To make it work, I already accepted that it's inevitable to be intrusive and I will need to add at least a tiny bit of code to class' body to get valuable reflection data.

However, I'd like to be as minimialistic here as possible. So, after studying some existing implementations, I found a concept that suits me. To simplify, the pattern looks like this:

```
class Base
{
    int baseFoo;
    double baseBar[5];
    RTTINFO(baseFoo, baseBar);
};

(...)

Base sth;
std::cout << TypeInfo(sth).variables[0].name; << std::endl;
// I don't mind if the way of accessing the type info changes totally
```

Using some generic programming, I can achieve pretty much hiding anything I like behind this `RTTINFO` macro and building type information structures. I can retrieve types, names, array size etc. But when I want to go one step further and introduce inheritance, like this:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    std::string foo;
    char* bar;
    /* RTTIPARENT(Base); <-- I want to avoid this */
    RTTINFO(foo, bar);
};
```

then I'd want to avoid specifing Base and still be able to get into its members' RTTI. I was hoping that there is some way for `Base` to smuggle some hints in its `RTTINFO(...)` for `Derived` to make it possible. So.. is there?

The main requirements are:

1. I don't want to specify a base class anywhere but the language-defined place. And I don't want to wrap `class Derived : public Base` in any macro.
2. `RTTIINFO` may add any necessary language and memory bias to the affected class.
3. I can put whatever I want into `RTTINFO` macro, even tons of code if necessary.
4. Both Base and Derived use the very same `RTTINFO` macro, which may be reused in further inferitance, of course. Let's leave out multiple inheritance problem, single inheritance seems complicated enough.
5. It's not necessary for `Derived` to be able to access RTTI of `Base`, it may be any other external helper class/function that would handle RTTI data. However, private member variables need to be supported.
6. I don't mind the compilation and runtime costs - if any calculation, like building inheritance tree, polling of all existing classes, whatever, must be done in runtime, there's always a way I could move it to program's initialization stage, so not a big deal for me.
7. If possible, avoid language-supported RTTI as I it must be turned off in some projects. Anyway, I didn't find a solution even with it.
8. No additional compilation step may be added.

One note: Maybe I could use `type_info::before()` but even if it would work for common compilers, C++ standard says I can't rely on inheritance relations here.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Andrew

Comment: How do you get the current class name in the macro?

Comment: Reflection belongs on your C++ "utility kit for the future" as much as a chainsaw belongs in a dentist's practice.

Comment: Exactly, if you want any kind of reflection/type information you'll end up with so many macros that it won't be useful. Just look at GObject

Comment: I didn't say I need it here (I wanted to make the problem as simple as possible), anyway, if I did, I could add an inline function and use `typeid(*this).name()`. Of course, this involves language-supported RTTI.

Comment: Please don't teach me on You Shall Not Use Reflections. I need it for diagnostics and it would like to turn it off in release code. One could find several applications, like serialization, as well.

Comment: @Andrew: [Boost seems to have no trouble implementing serialization without reflection support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/serialization/doc/index.html). Diagnostics is your debugger's job. We're not saying that you shouldn't use reflections so much as saying that you won't find it as useful as you think it is in practice with respect to C++ programs.

Comment: @In silico - thanks, I already took a look at Boost::Serialization. Unfortunately, it does use kind of "reflection" because I need to explicitly define a `serialize` method to make it work. So it's essentially not better than mine `RTTINFO`. About debugger - you're right, though there are cases where "F*ck-prints" work better than setting all the debugging options and breakpoints in multi-threaded, multi-process template-based code. If so, I'd like to make them more polite and descriptive.

Comment: Be aware that for true reflection, you will need information from the compiler that is not in the language.  The compiler may provide pragmas to access that information.  Otherwise you will have to add in those items in a base object class, much like Java and C# do.

Comment: There are certain things you can never have in C++. For example, you cannot take a runtime string that contains the name of an arbitrary class and instantiate an object of that class. That doesn't even make sense within the C++ object model. Java can do this because it forces *all* classes into a polymorphic hierarchy with a single base, so you know which type to put on the left-hand side. But C++ has no such restrictions, and hence cannot offer any such facilities.

Comment: @Thomas - these pragmas sound interesting to begin with. As most of my projects are GCC-based, is there such a pragma? I could not find anything about it.

Comment: You could customize GCC (e.g. extend it with MELT) to get these pragmas....

Comment: @Basile, MELT seems interesting, indeed (I ran across your presentation, btw), not only for this particular problem. Yet, for tasks like serialization, where I would like to use reflections in production code, I would need to provide such a compiler extension to a build system which I don't necessarily own. Anyway, it seems like yet another good reason to buy some parentheses and learn LISP at last.

Answer (score 3):

You won't have full reflection with current C++03 or C++11 compilers (because even C++11 don't have real reflection).

You could generate some meta-class code (look at the [Qt MOC](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html) as a nice example)

You could extend your C++ compiler. If it is GCC, consider making a plugin or a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension.

Comment: This is why I added 8). To me, adding a new compilation step has so many drawbacks that I'd better give up any attempts to get the reflection to work.

Comment: Then you need to generate C++ meta-class code like Qt does. Did you consider perhaps using `QObject` (that is, QCore, without any GUI)??

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, indeed, QObject would do, but it still needs `moc` to achieve it. I wasn't clear enough - by 'additional compilation step' I mean also code generation and preprocessing. However, do you think it might be possible to use Qt extensions only in debug configuration and keep the project (including SCM) maintainable at the same time? Or it's not worth it?

Comment: You cannot have meta-classes in a language not providing them. So you have to "generate code" if you want them. Your requests are contradictory!

Comment: Well, my first attempt is not to use explicitly-provided meta-classes and leave it to preprocessor to generate meta-classes from `RTTINFO` macro. Like I said, it's pretty easy to achieve much of reflection (which is: accessing members' list, their types, names, etc.) with only this single `RTTINFO(...)`, just take a look at [this example library](http://www.enchantedage.com/cpp-reflection). It's inheritance that I can't cross.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using code generation by setting up a kind of DSL (Domain Specific Language) and a little code generation framework that does the reflection stuff for you based on your class descriptions in that DSL. This probably only works for the data container and inheritance part, not for the behavioural part (i.e. methods), but as most Java advocats favour the anemic object model anyway, this fits perfectly into that trend.

And as C++ has true multiple inheritance, you have the ability to overcome that downside and derive your behavioural classes from the generated ones.

Stefan